# How to rename column with path in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, bigdata, avro

I am looking for a way to rename a column that is nested from my avro schema. I tried the options google has on their docs (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/manually-changing-schemas) but any time I try to alias or cast as a nested structure it doesn't work.

For example:

```
   SELECT
     * EXCEPT(user.name.first, user.name.last),
     user.name.first AS user.name.firstName,
     user.name.last AS user.name.lastName
   FROM
     mydataset.mytable
```

However this doesn't like aliasing with paths. Another option I am trying to avoid is pulling in all my previous avro files in and converting them using dataflow. I am hoping for a more elegant solution than that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to rebuild the structure at each level. Here's an example over some sample data:

```
SELECT
  * REPLACE(
    (SELECT AS STRUCT user.* REPLACE (
       (SELECT AS STRUCT user.name.* EXCEPT (first, last),
          user.name.first AS firstName,
          user.name.last AS lastName
       ) AS name)
    ) AS user)
FROM (
  SELECT
    STRUCT(
      STRUCT('elliott' AS first, '???' AS middle, 'brossard' AS last) AS name,
      'Software Engineer' AS occupation
    ) AS user
)
```

The idea is to replace the `user` struct with a new one where `name` has the desired struct type using the nested replacement/struct construction syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You have to re-build those structs. You can do something like this:

```
select 
  struct(
    struct(
      user.name.first as firstName, 
      user.name.last as lastName
    ) as name,
    user.height as height
  ) as user,
  address,
  age
from mydataset.mytable
```

Once you can verify the results, you can go about either creating a new table from these results or over-writing the existing table (which is essentially a workaround for renaming columns, but with caution). Hope it helps.